# Writing to __proto__ object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have an object like so:

```
const obj1 = {foo:'bar'};
```

and then I create a "copy", (`obj1` is now the **proto** of `obj2`):

```
const obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
```

if I call

```
obj2.foo = 3;
```

or

```
obj2.x = {};
```

my question is - will `obj1` ever get written to, or will it never be written to? As far as I know, only the top level object will get written to - the prototype object is never modified.

*In other words, are there any circumstances where is I set properties obj2, obj1 will get modified?*

Comment: Only if you set properties on `obj2.__proto__`, but that's considered bad practice anyway. Besides that, no.

Comment: no, the inheritance is read-only; it will return an exiting proto prop if the asked-for own prop is undefined, but it won't clobber a proto prop by setting.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that if the property on  `obj1` is an object reference to `someObj`, you can write to that object through `obj2`, i.e. `obj2.someObj.somProp = val`

Answer (score 0):

`obj1` can be written if it's accessed directly like `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj2).foo = 3` but it's unlikely that this can be done not on purpose.

It's possible to write to `obj1` not on purpose if it was designed without inheritance in mind, e.g.:

```
const obj1 = {
  get foo() { return obj1._foo },
  set foo(v) { obj1._foo = v}
}

const obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2.foo = 3;
```

Referring an object directly instead of `this` inside object methods was a common way to maintain proper context in legacy ES3/ES5 code.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any circumstances where is I set properties `obj2`, `obj1` will get modified?

Only when `obj1` has defined a setter property that is inherited by `obj2` (and what exactly happens then depends on the implementation of the setter). Otherwise, a property assignment on `obj2` will always create/change properties on `obj2` itself.

Comment: @MrCholo See the example in estus' answer :-)